# Too few arguments to function App\Imports\MyImport

Tags: php, laravel

I call my import as follows:

```
Excel::import(new MyImport(), $filePath);
```

In MyImport, I try to inject my repository a follows:

```
 public function __construct(
    protected MyRepository $myRepository,
) {}

/**
* @param Collection $collection
*/
public function collection(Collection $collection)
{
    $this->myRepository->create()...
```

I get the following error:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Imports\MyImport::__construct()
```

What is the proper way to inject repositories in Importer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use dependency injection in a class that is not resolved by the service container, you need to manually resolve the dependencies using the `app()` helper or the `resolve()` function.

In this code, `app(MyImport::class)` will create a new instance of `MyImport`, resolving its dependencies through the service container.

```php
$myImport = app(MyImport::class);
Excel::import($myImport, $filePath);
```